# How to calculate gradient of MSE in backpropagation?

Tags: machine-learning, python, gradient-descent, backpropagation, sgd

I want to implement a neural network from scratch to solve linear regression by using backpropagation. I don't understand how to compute the gradient of the MSE cost function with respect to each weight.

The formula I have say that:

for each weight $w_{jk}^l$, gradient is $\frac{∂C}{∂z_j^l}a_k^{l-1}$, where $j, k$ are the dimensions of the weight matrix $W$, 
$l$ is the layer, 
$z_j^l = \sum_{j=1}^m w_{jk}^l a_k^{l-1}+b_j^l$,
$m$ is the number of neurons in layer $l-1$, 
$C$ is the cost function, in this case MSE, 
$a_k^{l-1} $ is the activation function at layer $l-1$, 
and for each bias $b_j^l$, gradient is $\frac{∂C}{∂z_j^l}$

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot